# Is it possible to get remote executable name from gdbserver?

Tags: debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am working on graphical GDB frontend and I am curious if there is a way to obtain full executable name from a remote target assuming I don't have executable loaded in my local debugger.

I'm fine with using either CLI or MI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the PID through **"info inferiors"** and get ps(1) like output through **"info os processes"**. You'll then have to search the whole process list to find the matching PID and get its command line:

```
(gdb) info inferiors 
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 1    process 14382
(gdb) info os processes
pid        user       command    cores      
1          root       /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 22 1
2          root       [kthreadd] 3          
......
```

I checked the GDB source code, the relevant functions for "info os process" are [info_osdata_command()](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/osdata.c;h=8776022843b74328bf435225150df1aad3140c86;hb=HEAD#l292) and [get_osdata()](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/osdata.c;h=8776022843b74328bf435225150df1aad3140c86;hb=HEAD#l247). There's no builtin way to filter on a PID.